# Define Injected service on specific generic services in .NET Core

Tags: generics, .net-core, dependency-injection

I'm looking for a proper way to use DI in .NET Core with the example bellow.

I've got `LoggerStandardService` which inherits from `ILogger` service.
It's well injected in services (`EntityRepository<ModelA>`, `EntityRepository<ModelB>`)  but I would like to define another `LoggerCustomService` to inject in some specific generic service for instance in `EntityRepository<ModelC>`

Here is the code to perform this king of stuff.

```
public interface IEntityRepository<T> where T : class { }

public class EntityRepository<T> : IEntityRepository<T>
    where T : class
{
    public EntityRepository(IDbContext context, ILogger logger)
    {
        //Do some stuff
    }
}

public interface ILogger { }

public class LoggerStandardService : ILogger { }

public class LoggerCustomService : ILogger { }
```

In Startup.cs:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<IDbContext, DbContext>();
    services.AddScoped<ILogger, LoggerStandardService>();
    services.AddScoped<LoggerCustomService>();

    services.AddScoped<IEntityRepository<ModelA>, EntityRepository<ModelA>>();
    services.AddScoped<IEntityRepository<ModelB>, EntityRepository<ModelB>>();

    services.AddScoped<IEntityRepository<ModelC>, EntityRepository<ModelC>>
    (x =>
        new EntityRepository<ModelC>(
                x.GetRequiredService<IDbContext>(),
                x.GetRequiredService<LoggerCustomService>()));
```

Is the a proper way to perform this? Which avoid to define all other injected service in `EntityRepository<ModelC>` constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct term for what you are trying to accomplish is Context-Based Injection or Contextual Injection where you base the implementation of a dependency on its context (e.g. its parent, as in your case).

Microsoft's built-in DI Container (MS.DI) hasn't got good support for this, which typically means you have to use workarounds, like the workaround you applied. Downside of the workaround such as yours is that it becomes impossible to use Auto-Registration on the generic type, for instance:

```cs
services.AddScoped(typeof(IEntityRepository<>), typeof(EntityRepository<>));
```

With this registration you tell MS.DI to map any closed-generic version of `IEntityRepository<T>` to the compatible closed-generic implementation of `EntityRepository<T>`. It prevents you from having to make the registration for  `IEntityRepository<ModelA>`, `IEntityRepository<ModelB>`, `IEntityRepository<ModelC>`, `IEntityRepository<ModelD>`, etc. This ability is an extremely important feature that many DI Containers have, because it saves a lot of maintenance in your DI configuration when there are many models in your application.

But unfortunately, due to limitations of MS.DI, in your case, you're out of luck. Every closed `IEntityRepository<T>` registration has to be done explicitly, for instance using the method you already shown.

Another option is to make use of the `ActivatorUtilities` class. This makes the single `EntityRepository<ModelC>` registration more maintainable, because it allows you to only specify that one overridden dependency:

```cs
services.AddScoped<IEntityRepository<ModelC>>(x =>
    ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<EntityRepository<ModelC>>(x,
        x.GetRequiredService<LoggerCustomService>()));
```

`ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<T>` allows creating a new instance of the supplied `T`, while resolving all of its constructor's dependencies from the supplied service provider `x`, unless the dependency is supplied explicitly, which is done using the second argument `x.GetRequiredService<LoggerCustomService>()`.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much ! Have a nice day